# Open access journal with editor's summary

Tags: publications, journals

I'm looking for open access journals, whose scientific articles come with an editor's summary (not written by one of the authors!).

The articles and summaries will be used as data for benchmarking automated summary methods, so ideally the raw text would be easily accessible (not pdf if possible).

Perfect example: PLoS Medicine

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If this is off topic on this site, would you move it to data science stackexchange?

Comment: I reposted this on data science: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/open-access-journal-with-editors-summary?noredirect=1#comment14245_12902

Answer (score 2):

[Discrete Analysis](http://discreteanalysisjournal.com/) has been launched a few months ago. It's an arXiv overlay journal, so you have access to the raw text by following the link to the arXiv and clicking on "Other formats".